# FitSharp error while invoking test

Tags: fitnesse, fitsharp

I am using fitsharp for invoking an acceptance test. The code has compiled perfectly and when run from Visual Studio, runs without any problem. But when I invoke the same test from Fitnesse, it throws up an error "Cannot find the file Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder version 1.0.x.x". I have tried to check in the test project and all the referenced dlls but this particular library is not used anywhere. Also, I could not find the ObjectBuilder library with the same signature as mentioned above anywhere. Could someone help?

Comment: Can you post the FitNesse test page?

Comment: and the full exception.

Comment: Did you check the folders using by your application? Possible these libraries were not loaded because fitSharp tries to find then in the different folder. Try to set working folder directly.